# How to get the src element where the src element contains text "viewPdf"?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Below is the part of the inspect element output...

```
<html>
....
.....
<iframe id="g3GQfw" class="empPdfIFrame z-iframe" src="/emp/viewPdf?
id=1236222&amp;PdfDataSource=viewEmpPdfDataSource" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

There are many src elments in the entire html.

How to get this particular src element where it contains the text "viewPdf" ?

Basically i would like to extract the id associated in the above link.

Not sure what should be the xpath in the below

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("....."));<br>
string path = element.GetAttribute("src");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get xpath for iframe element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@src,'viewPdf')]");
```

This Xpath will give you all elements whose `src` attribute contains `viewPdf`